# Loop through folder and create Outlook emails

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a path T:\Fin\Reports\Final Reports

I save different reports for groups each month. The file get saved as the group names: **Acct, Pal, Mg, Qrt, etc.**

I have a chart where I plan to build my VBA that has in Cell G2, the group code and in Cell H2 the email address the files need to be sent to.

For instance:

- **Cell G2** = Acct
- **Cell H2** = Tim.Doe@Company.com
- **Cell G3** = Pal
- **Cell H3** = Jane.Doe@Company.com

I have this stock code for creating an email. How do I implement a `for loop` so it cycles through all the files in the folder and creates an individual email to each group and is addressed to the right email address?

```
Set xOutlookObj = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set xEmailObj = xOutlookObj.CreateItem(0)

With xEmailObj
    .Display
    .To = Range("H2")
    .CC = ""
    .Subject = "Monthly Report"
    .Attachments.Add ??????
End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Soemthing like this:

```vb
Const FPATH As String = "T:\Fin\Reports\Final Reports\"

Dim rw As Range, xOutlookObj, xEmailObj, attPath 

Set xOutlookObj = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Set rw = Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Info").Range("G2:H2")

do while application.counta(rw) = 2 'loop over rows while have content

    Set xEmailObj = xOutlookObj.CreateItem(0)
    With xEmailObj
        .To = rw.cells(2).value
        .CC = ""
        .Subject = "Monthly Report"
        attPath = FPATH & rw.cells(1).value & ".xlsx"
        Debug.Print rw.cells(2).value, attPath
        .Attachments.Add attPath
        .Display
    End With
   
    Set rw = rw.offset(1, 0)
loop
```

Comment: There is no need to use the `Display` method twice.

Comment: Hey Tim, Thanks for the code here. What I am experiencing after testing it is it loads up an email for the person in cell H2, but does not attach anything.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev - thanks I missed that it was already there...

Comment: Maybe you can add more detail about exactly how your files are named/stored...

Comment: I don't have much detail outside of they are all saved as an excel doc named as each group as seen in cells G2, G3, G4, and so on

Comment: I added some debugging information  -see what output you get.  Do the paths look correct?

Comment: I'm not sure what happened but I copy and pasted in your edits and it seems to be working this time. Maybe I accidently messed up the first copy paste job